# Where can I find drivers for Fujitsu Scansnap fi-5110 for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, scanner

I have a Fujitsu scanner that I cannot get working on Windows 7 x64.  I have downloaded both the TWAIN and ISIS x64 drivers from the [fujitsu website](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/support/drivers-downloads_index.html) but Windows still does not recognize.  I have tried it out using GIMP and Paint.net, neither program sees the scanner.  I have also tried the fi-5000N Configuration Tool from Fujitsu but to no avail.  Anyone know what drivers i need to install?

Here's the info on the back of the scanner:

Model: Fi-5110E0X2 
Part No: PA03360-B015 
Serial No: 026132 
Date: 2005-09

Answer (score 2):

Fi 5110 EOX is a ScanSnap scanner, in this case the scanner is already bundled with ScanSnap Manager to do the scanning. This scanner is not a TWAIN compliant scanner. The driver from the Fujitsu website you refer to is for the "fi 5110 C" which is completely different from ScanSnap scanners. So I think you have to find the ScanSnap Manager software that works with Windows 7.

Last time I tried to connect a ScanSnap s500 with ScanSnap Manager for S1500 it worked fine.

Comment: I tried installing whatever manager software Fujitsu had available at the time on their support site, but still could not get it working.  I ended up purchasing a new canoscan scanner, works great (really fast) and is has slimmer profile.

Comment: Just to confirm: I got my Fi-5110E0X2 (`USB\VID_04C5&PID_1096`) working by installing the ScanSnap Manager software. It does not support TWAIN and therefore won't work in other software, like GIMP or IrfanView.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post written by Robert Coop, which described how to edit the .inf file from fujitsu to make it install drivers for model fi-5110C, which works under windows 10.

[Fujitsu Artificial Market Segmentation (or, how to make a Mac ScanSnap FI-5110EOXM work in Windows 8.1](http://coopology.com/2014/10/fujitsu-artificial-market-segmentation-or-how-to-make-a-mac-scansnap-fi-5110eoxm-work-in-windows-8-1/)

The only thing you need to do is get the device Hardware Id from Windows Device Mgr, and use that in the inf file, replacing the hid of the C model.

However, editing the inf file will make the hash no longer match the file, and windows will issue a fatal error during installation, so you need to reboot into troubleshooting mode, and choose option 7 to allow installation of non- signed drivers. The process is explained in a link from his blog post.

Once the driver was installed, I installed an open source software program named NAPS2 (Not Another PDF Scanner) and created a profile for this scanner using TWAIN mode, and it worked great to scan both sides of the sheet in duplex mode, and ran OCR on it too!

Now instead of being forced to pay for a new scanner that works under Win10, I can allocate a portion of that unplanned expense for a donation to the OS software author. I hope you find this helpful.